# How to show price by calculating distance using graph with PHP and mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, algorithm

I am working on a project called the courier management system where I need to show the price of courier product price by calculating the receiver place to destination place by using a graph(the shortest path algorithm can be the Dijkstra algorithm for example).

Can anyone please help me with this?

I have no idea how to implement this, I am  a very beginner in this field

Comment: Implement the algorithm and if you get stuck, ask specific question to get help, here are but two sites that can get you started (2 of ~billions) https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dijkstra-s-algorithm-to-compute-the-shortest-path-through-a-graph, https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-visual-introduction/ .

Comment: I highly doubt it.  I think you are lost.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask] and read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question